# Wordpress Gutenberg ACF Blocks How to Add JS When Block is Opened

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using ACF Blocks and have the following block.

```
acf_register_block_type(array(
    'name'              => 'columns',
    'title'             => __('Columns'),
    'description'       => __('For complex multi colomn rows.'),
    // 'category'          => 'formatting',
    'render_template'   => get_template_directory() . '/includes/blocks/templates/columns.php',
    'enqueue_style'     => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/blocks/css/columns.css',
    'enqueue_script'    => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/blocks/js/columns.js',
    'keywords' => array('rows', 'content', 'column'),
    'supports' => array('align' => array('wide', 'full')),
    'mode' => 'auto',
));
```

I need to run some JS when I click on the block in the editor to open it for editing.  I don't know if there is a standard way of doing this so I thought I could just use a click event to run my function, but it won't fire.  Here is a pic of the block in the DOM.

[Block HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vXGI.png)

I added the script following the [docs here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/).  (At the bottom there is a "Adding block scripts" example)

Here is my trimmed down JS...

```
(function($){
    var initializeBlock = function ($block) {

        $('body').on('click', 'div[data-type="acf/columns"]', function () {
            console.log('teeeeeeeest');
        });

        //... Other JS put here works
    }

    if (window.acf) {
        window.acf.addAction('render_block_preview/type=columns', initializeBlock);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

How come this click function won't fire?  Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Just to check, is the JS actually included on the page? (can you find it in the page source? And does a `console.log('test')` outside the `initializeBlock` function fire?)

Comment: Are you using a child theme or a parent? If child then you should use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead. Anyway, check the network inspector if the js file is loaded.